# Where I can find my own Google+ Play reviews and ratings?

Tags: google-plus, google-play-store

I know that Google Play reviews and ratings are now connected with my Google+ account and my name.

But where exactly I can find a **list of my own reviews and ratings** on Google Play apps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing this changed since 2013, since now you can do this:

1. Go to https://play.google.com/
2. On the sidebar on the left, click "My Play activity".

This will bring up a page with all your app ratings and reviews.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately to this moment Google not provide such feature to list all our reviews and ratings from Google Play.

But there is method to search all of ours reviews by typing to google.com phrase:

```
inurl:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details +"John Doe"
```

where **John Doe** is our name we use in Google+, but of course this name should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I was equally frustrated with the lack of sorting/reviewing my Google Play activity. So here's what I did:

1. Download your [Google data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en). You can choose the Google products of which you want to download your data for. In this case, select “Google Play Store” and proceed next. Download your data in zip format and extract your data.
2. The files will be in **.json** format. Using suitable file opener app, open “**reviews.json**” file and there you go. You can review all your ratings and reviews on Google apps.

Answer (score -4):

You need to go to play.google.com and it's there that you can find the My Play Activity link on the menu and there they are, all your reviews! Yay!

(Btw it didnt come up when I used the link from the first answer on this thread but if u type in play.google.com yourself then that menu takes u to it)